# Drop down menu with text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Basically, I am looking for a drop down menu and you will click an option and it displays a table. If you check out the link below, it shows the code and a working preview (kind of). Basically, the problem I have is that it only works for the first 2 options and will not work for any of the other ones. The first 2, it works perfect though. Hopefully you will see what I mean. Any help would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/ca0cb7oz/

```js
function display(obj,id1,id2) {
txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
}
if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table width="340" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<thead>
<tr>
<td class="title">Start Location:</td>
<td class="field">
<select name="type" onchange="display(this,'Warr','CrFields','OldLivRd','Penk','Cuerd','Halt','Widn');">
<option>Please select:</option>
<option value="Warr">Warrington Interchange</option>
<option value="CrFields">Crossfields</option>
<option value="LivRd">Old Liverpool Road</option>
<option value="Penk">Penketh Road</option>
<option value="Cuerd">Cuerdley Cross</option>
<option value="Halt">Halton View</option>
<option value="Widn">Widnes Green Oaks</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="Warr" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<tr>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Adult Single</th>
    <th>Adult Return</th>
    <th>Child Single</th>
    <th>Child Return</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Crossfields</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Old Liverpool Road In</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Penketh Road</td>
    <td>£2.30</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Curdley Cross</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Halton View</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Widnes Green Oaks</td>
    <td>£3.30</td>
    <td>£4.80</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
<tbody id="CrFields" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<tr>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Adult Single</th>
    <th>Adult Return</th>
    <th>Child Single</th>
    <th>Child Return</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Crossfields</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Old Liverpool Road In</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Penketh Road</td>
    <td>£2.30</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Curdley Cross</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Halton View</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Widnes Green Oaks</td>
    <td>£3.30</td>
    <td>£4.80</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
<tbody id="OldLivRd" style="display: none;">
<tr>
<tr>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Adult Single</th>
    <th>Adult Return</th>
    <th>Child Single</th>
    <th>Child Return</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Crossfields</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Old Liverpool Road In</td>
    <td>£1.80</td>
    <td>£3.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Penketh Road</td>
    <td>£2.30</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Curdley Cross</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Halton View</td>
    <td>£2.80</td>
    <td>£4.00</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Widnes Green Oaks</td>
    <td>£3.30</td>
    <td>£4.80</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</tr>
<tbody id="Penk" style="display: none;">
<tr>

</tr>
<tbody id="Cuerd" style="display: none;">
<tr>

</tr>
<tbody id="Halt" style="display: none;">
<tr>

</tr>
<tbody id="Widn" style="display: none;">
<tr>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some `<tr/>`-tags are superfluous which means you might have an issue with HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: I am not very good with code. To be honest, I took a freely available code and tried to amend it to my needs and of course, it hasnt worked out. Do you know where the HTML problem may be?

Comment: Please see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp on how a HTML table looks like and compare it to yours. It's easier than you think.